# UIPickerView in separate view loses value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, nsuserdefaults

I have a UIPickerView with a lot of rows in a separate view, settingsViewController. When a row is selected it passes the data to my mainViewController, through NSUserDefaults. However, if I return to settingsViewController and, without changing row, push the save button - the pickerView seems to send the value 'nil'?

Here´s the code for the UIPickerView and the code passing the row.

```
//PickerViewCode
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [picker selectRow:[defaults integerForKey:@"pickerRow"] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:  
(NSInteger)component {
{
    if ([skolor count] == 0)
        return 1;
    return [skolor count];
}}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row 
forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [skolor objectAtIndex:row];
}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
   inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:row forKey:@"pickerRow"];

//Passing pickerViewValue
- (IBAction)selectedRow:(id)sender {

SchoolSoftViewController2 *vc1 = [self.storyboard 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webview1"];
NSString *urlString = [valdSkola absoluteString];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:urlString  forKey:@"UserURL"];
[self presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults doesn't save information immediately after it is set with a setObject:forKey: method call. To force it to save, tell it to synchronize after you set the urlString in defaults, but before you present the view controller.

```
NSString *urlString = [valdSkola absoluteString];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:urlString  forKey:@"UserURL"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[self presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And also where you set the row:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:row forKey:@"pickerRow"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: Well that part already works. It saves and in the mainViewController the right value is loaded. It is only when I return to settingsViewController and push save button without changing the value , the pickerView is still showing the same value, that it doesnt load in mainViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the picker selected value.like this.

int row = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:COMPONANT_INDEX]; 
NSString *str = [YOUR_ARRAY objectAtIndex:row];//it may crash, if the array is empty

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:str forKey:@"UserURL"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

in your case,
NSString *urlString = [valdSkola absoluteString]; // This is returning a nil